# Add .html to Woocommerce permalinks

Tags: permalinks, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm redesiging a site for a client using Wordpress and WooCommerce and I need to add .html to all the woocommerce permalinks so they don't lose any SEO ranking when we go live with the site.  Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?  I've searched far and wide, and cannot find a good answer.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Just add `.html` to your permalink structure in Settings > Permalinks

Comment: tried it, doesn't seem to take.

Comment: Just tested, seems like this only affects posts.

Comment: Yeah, any ideas?

Comment: This needs some investigating...

Comment: Any thoughts on this yet?  I've been searching around and cannot find anything useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the simplest way to add `.html`, which involves overriding the default permastructure:

```
function wpse_178112_permastruct_html( $post_type, $args ) {
    if ( $post_type === 'product' )
        add_permastruct( $post_type, "{$args->rewrite['slug']}/%$post_type%.html", $args->rewrite );
}

add_action( 'registered_post_type', 'wpse_178112_permastruct_html', 10, 2 );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_permastruct

For categories:

```
function wpse_178112_category_permastruct_html( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args ) {
    if ( $taxonomy === 'product_cat' )
        add_permastruct( $taxonomy, "{$args['rewrite']['slug']}/%$taxonomy%.html", $args['rewrite'] );
}

add_action( 'registered_taxonomy', 'wpse_178112_category_permastruct_html', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Make sure to, after adding the code, flush your rewrite rules by loading Settings > Permalinks.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked!  If I wanted to change the product category permalinks, would I use "( $post_type === 'product_category' )" ?

Comment: Not quite. See my revision. I also missed the 3rd argument in my original post (`$args->rewrite`), so make sure to add that in.

Comment: Its working but adding / at the end of every url : like: /magento.html/

Comment: @ShivSingh Make sure there is no trailing slash for your permalink structure settings e.g. `/%postname%` not `/%postname%/`